# How to concat in map function of reactjs

Tags: reactjs, concatenation, map-function

In below code what happening is concat is replacing the value in array instead of pushing it in react.

```
export default class Newsfeed extends Component {

 constructor(props, context) {
 super(props, context);
 this.imagemodal = this.imagemodal.bind(this)
 this.state = {
   imageArray:[],
   myimage:[{id:1,media:[{url:xyz},{url:abc}},
           {id:2, media:[{url:xyz}, {url:abc}]
  }




 this.state.myimage.map((myimage) => {
    if(someId === myimage.id){

     myimage.media.map((media)=>{

        this.setState({
          imageArray:this.state.imageArray.concat([media.url]),
          showimageslider:true,
          sid:sid
        },() =>console.log(this.state.imageArray.length))
      })

    }
  })
```

imageArray is over writing the array instead of concatenating it

Help me in this reagards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` function is asynchronous. You can try something like below

```
let mediaURLs = [];
this.state.myimage.map((myimage) => {
    if(someId === myimage.id){
      myimage.media.map((media)=>{
          mediaURLs.push(media.url);      
      })
    }
})
mediaURLs = mediaURLs.concat(this.state.imageArray);
this.setState({
  imageArray:mediaURLs,
  showimageslider:true,
  sid:sid
},() =>console.log(this.state.imageArray.length))
```

Comment: Why don't you use 'forEach' instead of 'map'. It might work a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `seState` function is asynchronous you need to do the normal operation -> form the array and then do `setState`

```
const imageArray = [];
this.state.myimage.map((myimage) => {
if(someId === myimage.id){

 myimage.media.map((media)=>{
    imageArray.push(media.url);  
  }
});
this.setState({
      imageArray:this.state.imageArray.concat(imageArray),
      showimageslider:true,
      sid:sid
    },() =>console.log(this.state.imageArray.length))
  })
```